# What's the meaning of 'module="foo"' attribute in api.xml tags?

Tags: api, configuration

I have this chunk of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <api>
    <resources>
      <mobile_api translate="title" module="mobile">
        <title>Milyuncarros Mobile API</title>
        <acl>mobile/api</acl>
        <model>mobile/api</model>
```

**Question**: What's the purpose of specifying `module="mobile"` and what values are allowed there? (in my case the value is "mobile"; i'm not asking about the particular value but the attribute itself)

I have this API currently working, but I did it by repetition (and adaptation) from tutorials - don't fully understand all the concepts and settings. I notice that attribute exists for many tags (e.g. `faults` tag and also `acl/resources` children tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the module helper to be used when translating. 
XML equivalent to `Mage::helper('mobile')->__($label)`

Comment: So the only use of module attribute is for translation purposes?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the case.